# Accepting multiple inputs in python logic

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())

arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
```

This is my code above which asks me to get an input n of number of elements in an array.

However, the source of confusion is that, since I am new to python, I can't understand why without using any for loops, I can provide multiple values to arrays?
I know lists are used here for conversion, input() for getting a value but this doesn't seem logical that just one input statement can allow me to enter 5-6 array values! I know map is used to iterate over an alterable from a given function though!

Another source of confusion for me is that if I remove rstrip() and split() from here, I get a compilation error! Why so?

```
arr = list(map(int, input()))
```

this is the error:

```
   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Isn't this amount of code enough to get integral array values?
Why is it that I have to use those string methods here?

(Note:- i know numpy supports arrays! using array word here just to tell you the problem being asked)

Comment: Compilation error is because you are missing one `)` at the end of the line.

Comment: thats a typo, editing it wait

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will split your input on whitespace character and return a list, e.g. for `"1 2 3 4 5"` you will get back `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`. That list is then used in `map` and `list` to convert it into a list of integers finally stored in `arr`.

If you do not use `split`, `int` will fail since `int('1 2')` cannot be parsed.

Comment: thnx got the string part but what about multiple inputs through a single line?

Comment: @GaganrajdeepSingh That is the point, if the user separates each input with e.g. a space, you can consider them as _separate inputs_, each in its own position in `arr`, if that is what you meant.

Comment: If you want `n` such lines of input, you need an explicit loop, like `[input() for _ in range(n)]`